# (C++) Dijkstra's Algorithm Backtracking issues

Tags: c++, algorithm, output, shortest-path, backtracking

I'm programming Djikstra's algorithm in C++ and I'm getting the correct distances from the source node to the end node but i'm having trouble backtracking the previous nodes visited. It's giving me sort of the correct answer but not the correct answer. Also I noticed with different input data of 1 as the start node and 16 as the finish node that my algorithm is using path's that aren't allowed (it goes from 1 -> 10 -> 8 when 8 isn't allowed) but that could just be me getting path backtracking wrong.

http://pastebin.ca/3188762  - Input data (1st = max nodes and then nodes(node num, x,y) then max edges then all edges with the last line being the start and finish node)

http://textuploader.com/awp89   - Output in console

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int nodeNum;
    double x, y;
};

void dji(double map[50][50],int startNode,int endNode,int maxNodes);

int main()
{
    int tempA, tempB, maxNodes, maxEdges, startNode, endNode;
    double tempD;
    double map[50][50];

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("ass03.txt");
    if(fin.good())
    {
        fin >> maxNodes;

        Node allNodes[maxNodes];
        for(int i = 0; i < maxNodes; i++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < maxNodes; k++)
            {
                map[i][k] = -1;
            }
            map[i][i] = 0;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < maxNodes; i++)
        {
            fin >> allNodes[i].nodeNum >> allNodes[i].x >> allNodes[i].y;
        }
        fin >> maxEdges;

        for(int i = 0; i < maxEdges; i++)
        {
            fin >> tempA >> tempB >> tempD;
            map[tempA-1][tempB-1] = tempD;
            map[tempB-1][tempA-1] = tempD;
        }

        fin >> startNode >> endNode;


        cout << "\t";

        for(int i = 0; i < maxNodes; i++)
        {
            cout << i+1 << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < maxNodes; i++)
        {
            cout << i+1 << "\t";
            for(int k = 0; k < maxNodes; k++)
            {
                cout << map[i][k] << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }


        dji(map, startNode-1, endNode-1, maxNodes);

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Incorrect filename" << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}




 void dji(double map[50][50], int startNode,int endNode,int maxNodes)
{
    int Intersections[maxNodes], path[maxNodes], temp; // equate for actual endNode
    double Distances[maxNodes];

    for(int a = 0; a < maxNodes; a++)
    {
        Intersections[a] = a;
        Distances[a] = map[startNode][a];

        if(map[startNode][a] != -1)
        {
            path[a] = startNode;
        }
        else
        {
            path[a] = -1;
        }
    }
    Intersections[startNode] = -1;
    Distances[startNode] = 0;

    double minValue = 99999;
    int minNode = 0;

    for(int l = 0; l < maxNodes; l++)//loop max amount of times to avoid having to function loop (disconsider l = startNode)?
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxNodes; i++)
        {
                if(Intersections[i] == -1)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if(Distances[i] > 0 && Distances[i] < minValue)
                {
                minValue = Distances[i];
                minNode = i;
                }
        }


        if(Intersections[minNode] == endNode)
        {
            temp = l;
        }

        Intersections[minNode] = -1;

        cout << " --- Used Node - " << minNode+1 << endl;

        for(int i = 0; i < maxNodes; i++)
        {
            cout << Intersections[i] << " ";

        }
        cout << endl;

        for(int i = 0; i < maxNodes; i++) 
        {
            if(map[minNode][i] < 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if(Distances[i] < 0) 
            {
                Distances[i] = minValue + map[minNode][i];
                path[i] = minNode;
                continue;
            }

            if((Distances[minNode] + map[minNode][i]) < Distances[i]) 
            {
                Distances[i] = minValue + map[minNode][i];
                path[i] = minNode;
            }
        }

        minValue = 99999;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < maxNodes; i++)
    {
        cout << "Node:"  << i+1 << " - PATH= " << path[i] << "     distance = " << Distances[i]  << endl;
    }

    cout << "Additional nodes used: " << temp << endl;

    temp = path[endNode];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << temp << " ";
        temp = path[temp];
    }

    /*temp = path[endNode];

    int temp2 = path[endNode];

    for(int i = 0; i < maxNodes; i++)
    {
        if(i == 0)
        {
            cout << endNode << " ";
            cout << temp << " ";
        }
        if(i%2 == 0)
        {
            if(temp != endNode)
            {
                temp = path[temp2];
                cout << temp << " ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << temp << " ";
                i = maxNodes;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(temp2 != endNode)
            {
                temp2 = path[temp]-1;
                cout << temp2 << " ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << temp2 << " ";
                i = maxNodes;
            }
        }
    }*/

    //cout << "PATH = " << endNode << " < - " << path[endNode] << " < - " << path[path[endNode]-1] << " < - " << path[path[path[endNode]-1]-1] <<  endl;

    //cout << "TEST" << path[4] << " " << path[8] << " " << path[16] << " " << endl;
}
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: [Don't delete and re-post your question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049853/dijkstras-algorithm-not-getting-the-correct-nodes) Don't reintroduce the wrong spelling and title that had been fixed in edits on your earlier question. Do keep the improvements that you have yourself made to your question, they're good improvements, but do them as an edit of your earlier question.

Comment: @hvd It was just because of the comment stream and I just wanted to clean it all up and my question changed completely because I made progress

Comment: Looking at both your old question and your new one, I still don't see them as different even knowing that you do think of them as such, but if they really are different, if an answer to your old question wouldn't answer your new question or vice versa, then that is indeed a valid reason for posting it as a new question. Your code doesn't appear to be complete yet, though. Aside from the missing `#include` lines and your `using` imports, you also reference a type `Node` that isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: @hvd Before I wasn't even getting the correct distances from a source node to a endnode but now I am, but my error is that when I backtrace I can't grab the correct nodes it used. Where as before, I wanted to just get the distances working. I've updated the code sorry, Node struct isn't used so I forgot to put it in.

Comment: @JacksonCollins Why are you not debugging your code?  If you have all of this planned out, why not debug to see where your program goes against your plan?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've tried debugging but I don't really understand where I'm going wrong

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the edit. There's always room for further improvements, but at least your results are now verifiable, that's a very important part of a good question.

Comment: @JacksonCollins Which means you didn't debug your code.  Again, if you have laid out the plan, *single step* through the program to see where the program goes awry.  At the very least, *you* should be identifying the function, set of lines, loop, whatever, that is not doing what you expected it to do.  You're not required to know *how* to fix the problem, just that you can identify the problem (instead of just dumping code and input to use).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it's the path array. It's supposed to be able to access the path through, 'cout << "PATH = " << endNode << " < - " << path[endNode-1] << " < - " << path[path[endNode-1]] << " < - " << path[path[path[endNode-1]]] << " < - " << path[path[path[endNode-1]]]' Which goes like this for 19 to 16, path[endNode-1] = 8 which then gets path[8] = 4 which then gets path[4] which should = 19 but it equals 20 in the array. I don't understand why

Comment: @JacksonCollins You're telling us what the final result should be, but that is not debugging.  Debug your program, and watch the `path` array and the values you're setting each element to and identify why the array is being set to those values.  Also *don't assume what the values should be* -- run your program in a debugger and *verify* that the values are what they are..     Path started out at some values, so step through your code to see how, when, and where the path values are being set.  Seriously, debugging is part and parcel of learning how to write programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're mixing zero-based and one-based indexing. Your vertices are numbered 1-20, and those are the numbers that end up in your `path` array with valid indices 0-19. You then use the vertex number as the index into the array.

Change your code to either consistently use the vertex number, or consistently use the array index.

Comment: Could you highlight which part? I know what you're talking about but which of path am I using wrong? Cause i access it with endNode-1

Comment: @JacksonCollins `temp` is initially set to `path[endNode-1]`, which gives it the value of a vertex number. You then set it to `path[temp]`, where you're assuming it's an array index. You have that same problem again on the line printing "PATH = (...)".

Comment: So would I set it to path[temp]-1? or? Could you edit my question with what you think is correct

Comment: @JacksonCollins That's not how it's supposed to work here on SO. Editing the question in a way that gets rid of the problem means the question becomes useless for any future readers. Anyway, I included two alternatives in my answer: either use the zero-based numbering consistently, or use the one-based indexing consistently. `temp=path[temp]-1;` would be wrong if you use either zero-based or one-based indexing for both `temp` and `path`. It could be correct if `temp` is zero-based, and `path` is one-based. But that means you also need to update the other uses of `temp` to match.

Comment: @JacksonCollins I personally think the code becomes more understandable if you change both `temp` and `path` to be zero-based, which means you would need to change a little more than just the output, but yes, if you decide to change only the part of the code that prints the results, you would still be able to make it work.

Comment: I tried to change it to zero-based but i'm still getting incorrect path output from backtracking from the endNode

Comment: Please check my edit, I don't know what to change to get it to work

Comment: @JacksonCollins You're already printing correct results now as far as I see. (Not in the commented-out part, that would need some tweaking if you uncomment it.) It's just that you're printing zero-based results. To print one-based results, add one before printing.